# How do I generate page numbers when using the html2latex library?

Tags: html

I'm using the html2latex library to convert some html pages to LaTeX files, and I would like to generate page numbers, and then be able to control the formatting/placement of the numbers.

Does html2latex include options to allow for this kind of manipulation, without having to extend the library?

Comment: As it stands this is 'unclear': we need more detail of the HTML and desired LaTeX output.

Comment: You should now be able to edit your question.

Comment: I've since been able to identify the answer to my question. It is "Use the <pdf:pagenumber> special component in your footer content frame". I'm not sure how to rephrase the question, so that it's obvious this is the answer I am looking for.